# Does PHP copy object data structures when I pass objects to functions or methods?

Tags: php

I know there's the option to pass a value by reference, simply by writing something like

```
function foo(&$bar) {...}
```

But from Objective-C I'm used to believe that objects are *always* passed by reference (since the variables referencing them are just pointers whose values are just a memory address). Only sctructures and primitives would have to explicitely be passed by reference.

How's that going on in PHP? Must I be sure to put that address operator & into every parameter to enhance performance when passing objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only in versions prior to PHP5. In PHP5 objects are always passed by reference.

Comment: Is this the case? The docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php would seem to suggest otherwise. Then again, I'm relying on the PHP docs being accurate and up to date which isn't always the best idea. :-)

Comment: "regular" variables are passed by value, objects are passed by reference. This is for PHP5. You can force the pass-by-reference for "regular" variables with &. In PHP4 objects ware passed by value, and you had to use & for objects.

Comment: Just seen the doc that @txyoji posted - +1

Comment: I think Jan's got it right. Here is the php5 part of the manual. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: And though the doc specifically says `"objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true` the object itself is not passed by value. Only the "object identifier" is passed by value but it "references" the same object.

Answer (score 0):

PHP5 passes object by reference. To pass them by value you can use the keyword clone.